# problemas al importar una función en Python

Tags: python, funciones, python-import

Quiero importar la función materias que esta en el modulo Ejercicio_40.py

```
def materias():
    lista = []
    while True:
        materia = input("Introduce una materia\n")
        if materia != "salir":
            print ("¿" + materia.capitalize(), end=" ")
            respuesta = input("es correcto?\n")
            if respuesta == "si":
                lista.append(materia)
            elif respuesta == "no":
                print (materia,"no ha sido agregado")
            else:
                print ("Error.Introduce si o no")
        elif materia == "salir":
            break   
    return lista

def escribir():
   ls = materias()
   for i in ls:
       print ("Yo estudio",i,end=", ")

escribir()
```

El problema es que cuando importo en otro modulo me lo ejecuta dos veces no se porque

```
from Ejercicio_40 import materias
lista = materias()
print (lista)
print [lista[0]]
```

Comment: Hola Steven Bienvenido!! La identación, no es correcta. Por favor puedes corregir el código, así será más fácil ayudarte :) . Te recomiendo también leer [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que cuando haces un `import modulo` lo que hace python es cargar **y ejecutar** el contenido completo de `modulo.py` (lo mismo si haces `from modulo import algo`).

Eso es necesario, ya que es la ejecución del módulo la que define las funciones y clases que haya dentro. Hasta que python no haya ejecutado un `def funcion` la función no está definida.

Naturalmente ejecutar un `def` no es lo mismo que ejecutar la función. Cuando ejecuta el `def` la función simplemente queda definida, pero el código de la misma no se ejecuta aún hasta que la función no es *invocada*.

Lo que ocurre en tu caso es que el módulo, además de definir la función, también la invoca. En la última línea del módulo tienes la llamada `escribir()`, lo que invoca a esta función, y ella a su vez contiene una invocación a `materias()`. Por lo tanto cuando se importe ese módulo, la función `materias()` será ejecutada. Además, la vuelves a ejecutar desde el programa principal.

## Soluciones

La solución obvia es eliminar la línea `escribir()` que tienes al final del módulo. De ese modo cuando lo importes se ejecutarán las definiciones, pero no la invocación y así evitas que se llame a la función durante la importación. Pero si haces eso, al intentar ejecutar "normalmente" ese ejercicio poniendo `python Ejercicio_40.py` no ocurrirá nada (en realidad sí ocurre que se definen las funciones, pero ya que has quitado la línea que las llamaba, una vez definidas el programa terminaría sin hacer nada más).

La solución más habitual es poner la llamada a `escribir()` dentro de un condicional especial, que hace que esa función no se invoque cuando el módulo sea importado, pero sí cuando sea ejecutado "normalmente" como script. Se hace así:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    escribir()
```

Si pones eso al final de `Ejercicio_40.py` (en lugar de la llamada a `escribir()` que tú tienes), logras dos propósitos:

- Cuando haces `import` de ese script, la condición del `if` será falsa, porque la variable `__name__` contendrá el nombre del módulo que está siendo importado (que sería en este caso `"Ejercicio_40"`, y ya que eso es distinto de `"__main__"`, la condición no se cumple y `escribir()` no se ejecuta.
- Pero cuando ejecutas desde línea de comandos el script poniendo `python Ejercicio_40.py`, resulta que Python inicializa la variable `__name__` con el valor `"__main__"`, por lo que en ese caso la condición es cierta y `escribir()` sí se ejecuta.

Gracias a lo segundo, el Ejercicio_40 seguirá funcionando como antes, es decir, se puede ejecutar desde línea de comandos. Y gracias a lo primero podrá funcionar también como módulo sin causar efectos secundarios. Es decir, podrá ser importado sin que se ejecute `escribir()`.